# How to define a type/class in Python dynamically?

Tags: python, c, c-preprocessor, code-generation

In **C**, if I want to define a type from a name I could use the preprocessor. For example,

```
#define DEFINE_STRUCT(name)        \
    struct My##name##Struct        \
     {                             \
        int integerMember##name;   \
        double doubleMember##name; \
     }
```

And then I could define a concrete struct like so

```
DEFINE_STRUCT(Useless);
```

and use the `Useless` struct like this

```
struct MyUseslessStruct instance;
```

So my question is

- Is there a way to achieve this in Python?

I have the following class

```
class ClassName(SQLTable):
    items = []
    def __init__(self, value):
        SQLTable.__init__(self)
        # some common code
        if value in self.items:
            return
        self.items.append(value)
```

For each `ClassName` the contents of `items` will be different, so I would like something like

```
def defineclass(ClassName):
    class <Substitute ClassName Here>(SQLTable):
        items = []
        def __init__(self, value):
            SQLTable.__init__(self)
            # some common code
            if value in self.items:
                return
            self.items.append(value)
```

I don't want to repeat the code over and over, I would like to generate it if possible.

Comment: Try this: [meta class in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/298607)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close:

```
def defineclass(ClassName):
    class C(SQLTable):
        items = []
        def __init__(self, value):
            SQLTable.__init__(self)   
            # some common code
            if value in self.items:
                return
            self.items.append(value)
    C.__name__ = ClassName
    return C
```

As you can see, you define it using a placeholder name, then assign its `__name__` attribute. After that, you return it so you can then use it as you desire in your client code. Remember, a Python class is an object just as much as any other, so you can `return` it, store it in a variable, put it into a dictionary, or whatever you like once you've defined it.

The `__name__` attribute is a convenience, mainly so error messages make sense. You may not actually need to give each class a unique name.

An alternative for this particular use case might be to use subclassing:

```
class Base(SQLTable):
    def __init__(self, value):
        SQLTable.__init__(self)   
        # some common code
        if value in self.items:
            return
        self.items.append(value)

class Thing1(Base): items = []
class Thing2(Base): items = []
```

By not defining `items` on the base class, you ensure that you must subclass it and define a per-class `items` to actually *use* the class.

Comment: Interesting, I used the `__name__` member for other things in other classes, but I never thought I could assign to it. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: So the `items` variable will be diferente each time I call this fuction even if I pass the same `name`?

Comment: Yes. Class (and function) definitions are *executed* in Python. So each time you call the function, you get a new class. You can check their `id()` to be sure.. Of course, you could just use subclasses...

Answer (score 1):

kindall's answer is very clear and likely preferable, but there is a built-in function to generate classes: [`type`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type). When called with one argument, it returns the type of an object. When called with three arguments it generates a new type/class. The arguments are class name, base classes, and the class dict.

```
def custom_init(self, value):
    SqlTable.__init__(self)
    if value in self.items:
        return
    self.items.append(value)

def defineclass(classname):
    #           __name__   __bases__    __dict__
    return type(classname, (SQLTable,), { '__init__': custom_init,
                                          'items': [] })
```

Comment: That's the kind of thing I don't like about python or c++, a function should do one and just one thing.

Comment: @kindall it's a class variable not an instance variable

Comment: Yes, and it would be a class variable if you defined it with `type()`. E.g. `type(classname, (SQLTable,), { '__init__': custom_init, 'items': [] })`